# Linux switches to mysterious Kernel Buffer view everytime a new dmesg arrives

Tags: linux, terminal, tty

There is a mysterious tty that only reacts to sysrq, not to any other keyboard input.

It started after I engaged <kbd>SysRQ</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

Every 30 seconds or so, Linux switches away from the current tty to that strange, uncontrollable tty that contains the most recent dmesg's.

Each line starts with the uptime such as [2312154.4828572]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> does not get me out of there.

What is this mysterious tty?

Comment: If ctrl+alt+f# does not get you out of there, then how do you know it happens every 30 seconds?  aren't you stuck in it already?  Or is there another way to switch out of it?

Comment: @SourceJedi I already restarted my computer. The next time this phenomenon happens, I will examine it further. It gets unstuck after around 30 seconds and leaves me on a black tty7 (not even blink cursor). However, I can then switch to my desired tty.

Comment: Did you try SysRQ+R? That might let ctrl+alt+f# work, in case the tty is in raw mode.

Comment: Where does your kernel come from?  What is your Linux distribution (and version) ?

Comment: Sysrq+R did not work. Mine was Linux Mint Xfce 18.2 (live session). Now using Linux Mint KDE 18.3 (live session). Each in 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your mysterious “kernel buffer view” seems to be similar to what the system looks like when it’s only running the kernel and an `init` process. (But that doesn’t explain the apparent console switching.)

<kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> [kills all processes apart from `init`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html). Your desktop session is gone, all the system dæmons are gone… `init` should restart some `getty`s, so you should be able to log in, but perhaps it isn’t doing this on your system. So you end up on one of the virtual consoles; whichever one you switch to will look similar to any other, but the kernel messages only go to the current virtual console, which results in the impression you describe.

In this situation, there’s nothing to recover apart from unflushed data, so <kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> is the way to go.

Comment: But it switches from the tty's I can interact with to the “kernel buffer view” and back. Unlike usually, where it would print directly into the currently active tty, “kernel buffer view” acts as if it were a seperate tty but it blocks the keyboard. When it switches back to the interactable state, the contents in the usual tty's are not gone.

Comment: Side note: Thank you for reminding me about the <kbd>KBD tag</kbd>.

Comment: Please do not delete it. Your answer is still informative.

Comment: I unaccepted it for  now to signalize to other users that this question is open. Do not take it personally.

Comment: No worries, I’m also curious to find out what’s going on here ;-).